# Protractor - How to extract a link from HTML string?

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, jasmine, e2e

In one of my test cases, I'm able to get the entire HTML e-mail message sent to a user. The message contains text, button, a link, etc.

My Issue is that I need to extract the href link in order to use it for the next function. I have been checking the [protractor API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api), unfortunately I was not successful in finding the correct method which can be used in this case.

E.g. of **HTML message:**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td align="center">
         <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
               <tr>
                   <td>
                      <a href="http://domain.io/ui/confirm?d=true&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUz....
                   </td>
               </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can I extract the `<a href..` value? I mean how can I get the link?

Comment: What is your output when you use the `getText` method?

Comment: @demouser123: The output is the code I have posted in my question. Any way, issue has been solved. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed. My bad... was thinking more complicated than it's. It's even not something protractor specific. just native JavaScript

Solution:

**`var getHref = email['html'].match(/href="([^"]*)/)[1];`**